# Graph database for JavaEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, content-management-system, graph-databases

I would like to create CMS in JavaEE. I want use graph database. Which graph database is good for this purpose? What do you recommend? I seek free/open source graph database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can personally encourage you to use neo4j - http://neo4j.com/. It's new, quite simple, easy to use on Java and has quite good documentation. Although be aware of some minor issues (like an application crashing occasionaly when used heavily).